# Delphi - функция копирования свойств аудита файла или папки в windows?

Tags: delphi, файлы

Не получается копировать свойства аудита файла и/или папки. Хотя **SeAuditPrivilege** и **SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION** отвечающие за аудит стоят.
Выставленные привилегии приложения: **SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege, SeSecurityPrivilege, SeBackupPrivilege, SeRestorePrivilege, SeAuditPrivilege**.
Ошибки при выполнении функции не происходит но и свойства аудита не копируются.

Функция копирования:

```
function CopyAuditAndSec(const inFile, outFile: string): Boolean;
var
psd: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
dwSize: DWord;
SecurityInformation: SECURITY_INFORMATION;
begin
result := true;

SecurityInformation :=  OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION +
                        GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION +
                        DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION +
                        SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION;

psd := nil;
if not GetFileSecurity(PChar(inFile), SecurityInformation, Pointer(1), 0,
  dwSize) and (GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
  begin
    try
      try
        psd := HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap, 8, dwSize);
        if psd <> nil then
          begin
            if not(GetFileSecurity(PChar(inFile), SecurityInformation, psd,
              dwSize, dwSize)) then
              begin
                result := false;
              end;

              if lTest then
              begin
                Exit;
              end;

            if not(SetFileSecurity(PChar(outFile),SecurityInformation, psd)) then
              begin
                result := false;
              end;
          end;
      except
        on e: Exception do
          begin
            result := false;
          end;
      end;
    finally
      if psd <> nil then
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap, 0, psd);
    end;
  end
else
  begin
    result := false;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Для начала было бы неплохо посмотреть что вернет `GetLastError` после второго вызова. И еще у вас какая-то странная конструкция в первом вызове: `..., Pointer(1), ...`.

Comment: да, действительно, ошибка ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER. Возникает тогда разумный вопрос а сколько надо резервировать? SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH тоже недостаточно т.к. это минимальный размер.

Comment: Предлагаю сделать сначала dwSize := dwSize + 2, а потом psd := AllocMem(dwSize);

Comment: И вам еще понадобится привилегия *SE_SECURITY_NAME*. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446639(v=vs.85).aspx _To read the SACL of a file or directory, the SE_SECURITY_NAME privilege must be enabled for the calling process._

Comment: SE_SECURITY_NAME это и есть SeSecurityPrivilege.

Answer (score 1):

проблема была решена сменой 
    HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap, 8, dwSize);
на
    GetMem(psd,dwSize);
и
    FreeMem(psd, dwSize);
соответственно. 
Код заработал.

Comment: Лучше все-таки использовать `AllocMem` вместо `GetMem`. `AllocMem` делает ровно тоже самое + заполняет выделенную память нулями, чтобы там не было "мусора". Так безопаснее.